# Generate MB of random data in C#

Tags: c#, random, base64, url-encoding

I have an algorithm that generates random data of KB order.

```
byte[] linkBytes = new byte[size * 1024];
var rngCrypto = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rngCrypto.GetBytes(linkBytes);
String text128 = Convert.ToBase64String(linkBytes);
String text128Enc = Uri.EscapeDataString(text128);

return text128Enc;
```

The problem is that I need MB's of random data in Base64.
On MSDN says that EscapeDataString cannot exceed 32766 chars approx. the int size.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could switch to url safe Base64 which leaves out the padding and uses `_` and `-` as special characters.

Comment: Yes that works too, but @Guffa helped me big time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a base64 encoded string only can contain three characters that needs URI encoding, you can just replace those three:

```
string text128Enc = text128.Replace("+", "%2b").Replace("/", "%2f").Replace("=", "%3d");
```

I tested this on a base64 tring created from 100 MB of data, and it takes about one second to encode that string.